# Iterative point feature removal based on Thiessen polygon values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, voronoi-thiessen, iteration

The background is: I have point feature class and Thiessen polygons created based on it. I wanted to know for each point Thiessen polygon area value, so I have calculated Thiessen polygon area value and added this information to point class. I have also sorted points based on Thiessen polygon areas in descending order, so the first point in a table has the biggest Thiesssen polygon area.

The task is to remove first point with the biggest Thiessen area, then rebuild Thiessen polygons (without deleted point), update Thiessen areas for points, sort them again, check first on the list, remove it and so on until the number of points that left is equal to some fixed number.

I am working in ArcGIS 10.1 and I am using ModelBuilder. Do you think I can achieve something like this in ModelBuilder?  How for example take the first point on the list?Or the point with max attribute value?And which tools should I use for iteration/loop?

Comment: I think this *could* be done using ModelBuilder but would be far easier to get working and better performing if scripted with ArcPy.

Comment: I am not very experienced ArcPy user but I can try. Have you got any further suggestions?

Comment: Use a Unique ID to identify the point you want to delete and then Select_analysis to pull all but that point into a new feature class, and then rebuild your Thiessen polygons.  Actually ModelBuilder may be OK after all.  Perhaps start putting together a model that just does that first part and if you get stuck post a picture of those few elements from your model and make that the focus of this Question.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for suggestions. Actually I wanted to automate it as much as possible. Thus I managed to select the point with max Thiessen polygon value by subquery: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=SQL_Reference. But still don't know how to select everything without the max value from a table :). Working on this...:)